# View escapes node's text field HTML

Tags: views, 8

I've looked at other posts but been unable to resolve the issue. I have a Text field (formatted, long) in a content type, when the node is viewed the HTML in the field displays correctly, when I view the fields in the database it is stored as raw HTML, however, when I add one of these fields to my view, the output is escaped as < and so on and therefore displayed in the browser as HTML rather than marking up the text.

I've seen a few posts suggesting modification of the twig template, however a) this didn't seem to work for me and b) I'm looking to do this within the view / module so it is applicable regardless of which theme is in use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are your field `Formatter` and `Rewrite results` settings? Does it work well in Views Preview or in Bartik theme?

Comment: The dev theme is Bartik, will be working on the new theme when the structure is sorted.

Formatter has been tried in Default and trimmed and I get the same result.

No rewrite enabled

Get the same on preview and when viewing the page, have tried viewing on incognito window without logging on so see the same whether anonymous user or logged in administrator.